# error on rake db:migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, rake

I am new at ruby and also rails. I can't why my rake db:migration is returning me this error

/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake.rb:30:in `require': no such file to load -- rbconfig(LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rake.rb:30
    from /usr/bin/rake:25:in`require'
    from /usr/bin/rake:25

thanks!

Comment: could you post full trace?

Comment: how did you install `ruby` and `rails`? have you used `rvm` for `ruby`??

Comment: I figured out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are using the right ruby version with `$ ruby -v` use `$ rvm 1.9.3 --default` (or the version you are using) in that case. Also, run `$ bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed out typing the end of the

```
require '
```

in a file you were working on.

Answer (score 0):

The error should be fixed adding in the Gemfile (in the root folder of your app) the lines:

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

and run `sudo bundle`